# How to Redirect Input to SQL*Plus without Exiting using Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, oracle, pipeline, io-redirection, powershell-5.1

Using Windows PowerShell, how do I redirect input into `sqlplus` (non-interactive stdin mode) such that once the redirected input is complete `sqlplus` is left open in interactive stdin mode without SQL*Plus exiting?

It appears as though the redirected input is issuing an implicit `exit` which SQL*Plus is processing.

Using Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition, Oracle InstantClient 19c 64-bit, Windows PowerShell Desktop 5.1.19041.1320, Microsoft Windows 10.0 build 19042.

Thank you in advance.

*dev.sql*

```
set echo on
set serveroutput on
exec dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
```

No redirection executes start script `dev.sql` and does **not** exit (notice the `SQL>` prompt as the last line instead of `PS C:\Users\my>`).

```
PS C:\Users\my> sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service" "@dev.sql"

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 15 14:44:48 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 15 2022 14:40:03 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

However, when redirecting the input, then SQL*Plus automatically exits (notice the `PS C:\Users\my>` prompt as the last line instead of `SQL>`).  No matter how I redirect the input into `sqlplus`, SQL*Plus automatically exits.

Redirection with `Get-Content`.

```
PS C:\Users\my> Get-Content dev14.sql | sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service"

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 15 14:48:42 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 15 2022 14:44:49 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL> SQL> SQL> hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0
PS C:\Users\my>
```

Redirection with *here-string*.

```
PS C:\Users\my> @"
>> set echo on
>> set serveroutput on
>> exec dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
>> "@ | sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service"

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 15 14:50:14 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 15 2022 14:48:44 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL> SQL> SQL> hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0
PS C:\Users\my>
```

Single line redirection.

```
PS C:\Users\my> "select * from dual;" | sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service"

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 15 15:03:10 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 15 2022 15:00:34 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL>
D
-
X

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0
PS C:\Users\my>
```

Redirect using `Start-Process`.

```
PS C:\Users\my> Start-Process sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service" -RedirectStandardInput dev.sql -NoNewWindow -Wait

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 15 15:06:20 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 15 2022 15:06:07 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL> SQL> SQL> hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0
PS C:\Users\my>
```

Redirecting using batch, still causes SQL*Plus to exit.

*dev.bat*

```
(
echo set echo on
echo set serveroutput on
echo exec dbms_output.put_line('hello world'^^^);
) | sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service"
```

```
PS C:\Users\my> c:dev.bat

C:\Users\my>(
echo set echo on
 echo set serveroutput on
 echo exec dbms_output.put_line('hello world'^);
)  | sqlplus my_username/my_password@"my_host:my_port/my_service"

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 15 15:57:51 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 15 2022 15:57:38 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL> SQL> SQL> hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0
PS C:\Users\my>
```

Note: I tried using `-noexit` but that is an argument to executing `powershell` itself not `sqlplus`.

It is like `sqlplus` says "okay, no more `stdin`, I'm done".  Maybe there is a way to direct `stdin` back to they keyboard once pipped input reaches end-of-file, so `sqlplus` is left waiting for the next keyboard input?

Note: It is also odd how we do not see the `set serveroutput on` getting echoed.

Thank you.

Comment: sqlplus automatically exits when its' input pipe (stdin) is closed. So the only option is to do not close pipe(you can write a program that starts sqlplus and feeds it's stdin and closes it only when you want)... For me it's much better to pipe to file and then execute it . Why do you want to leave it opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlplus automatically exits when its' input pipe (stdin) is closed. So the only option is to do not close pipe: you can write a program that starts sqlplus and feeds it's stdin and closes it only when you want.

I don't know why do you want to leave it open in non-interactive mode.
For me it's much better to pipe to file and then execute it.

Don't know will it help you, but I have a couple of workarounds how to leave it open for some time: use `host` command. For example the following command will leave sqlplus opened for 15 seconds:

```
"host powershell Start-Sleep -s 15"  | sqlplus  user/pass@//host:port/service
```

Note that you can't do anything with interactive stdin within it, like

```
"host timeout /t 10" | sqlplus  user/pass@//host:port/service
```

because

```
SQL> ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.
```

Comment: obviously you can also use `dbms_lock.sleep` (or dbms_session.sleep since Oracle 18), but it requires open connection to database (and extra call)

Comment: @Malakshinov.  
Thank you for your thoughts.  I want to leave ``sqlplus`` open in *interactive* mode after I've redirected input.  I've edited the question to attempt clarify this point. 

Based on your comment *"Sqlplus automatically exits when its input pipe (stdin) is closed"*, is it *not* possible for ``sqlplus`` to switch back to interactive stdin mode once it's been started in non-interactive stdin mode?

Comment: @AlexBartsmon yes, unfortunately, sqlplus doesn't support switch betwe interactive <-> non-interactive modes